# How do I get the scale of the map item in my Layout(composer) in Qgis3?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I want to get the scale of my Layout that I created. For this I thought of using the `QgsLayoutItemMap` class. The problem is that the scale method in `QgsLayoutItemMap` always returns `0.0`. I know I am doing something wrong but I don't know what. Here is the code I am using:

```
projectInstance = QgsProject.instance()
projectLayoutManager = projectInstance.layoutManager()
item = projectLayoutManager.layoutByName("asd")
tail = QgsLayoutItemMap(item)
tail.scale()
```

Comment: you want to use the scale inside pyqgis or do you want to show the scale as a numeric value in a label in your print composer?

Comment: I want to show the scale as a numeric value in a label.

Comment: Your questio is for qgis2, mine is for qgis3. In qgis3 there is no such thing as composer, it's called layout now.

Comment: ups your right my bad!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved the mystery about the scale. First I have to search for the `layout` I want to use:

```
projectInstance = QgsProject.instance()
projectLayoutManager = projectInstance.layoutManager()
projectLayoutManager.layouts()
```

With this we get all `layouts` that we have. Then we chose which one we want to use.

```
layout = projectLayoutManager.layouts()[0]   #chose layout
```

The method `referenceMap` in `QgsLayout` is what we need now. Let's say our `layout` is a `QgsPrintLayout`. Because `QgsPrintLayout` inherits all methods from `QgsLayout`, we can use the `referenceMap` method and that will help us use the `scale` method in `QgsLayoutItemMap`. And then we can use our `scale` method to get our scale. Here is the rest of the code:

```
referencemap = layout.referenceMap()
referencemap.scale()
```

Answer (score 7):

Your solution is using Python.
I'm gonna give how to get the scale using a QGIS Expresion only:

First, set a ITEM ID on your map item, in the tab properties:
[image: map item ID]

Then, in your label, you the expression:

```
 [% map_get(item_variables( 'map1' ), 'map_scale') %]
```

This is will output the scale of the map called 'map1'.